# CKEditor 4 (replace by class name) get text area value

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to create a preview function in a CKEditor instance.

I'm using CKEditor 4 and am replacing textareas by class name, the only issue I am facing is that I cannot get the value of the textarea using JavaScript, this is what I've tried so far:

```
function prev()
    {
        html=document.forms["1_form"]["editor1"].value;
        document.getElementById("prev").innerHTML = html;
    }
```

and the CKEditor textarea:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" onkeydown="prev()"></textarea>
```

Why doesn't this work? If I disable CKEditor, the script functions as expected, but not with ckeditor enabled. What am I supposed to  do?

Thanks!

Edit:

I am now trying to do it with replace and this is the code I'm using:
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1'); //new ckeditor instance
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1; //reference to instance

```
//on `key` event
editor.on('key', function(){

var data = editor.getData(); //reference to ckeditor data
$('#prev').html(data); //update `div` html

});
```

it works but the only this is, it updates only after the next key is pressed so say the value of the editor is `hello world` it will show the preview as `hello worl` what can I do to this code to fix it, please ignore the first set of code.

Answer (score 4):

This is because CKEDITOR replace your `<textarea>` into `<div>` with `contenteditable="true"` attribute and there is no `value` property in DOM for `<div>` element.

You need to add event listener to CKEDITOR instance, not to DOM element, for example:

```
// check if editor is ready
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( e ) {

        // check if DOM is ready
        e.editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {

            // bind "keydown" event to CKEDITOR
            e.editor.document.on('keydown', function( event ) {

                // write editor content into "prev" element
                document.getElementById( "prev" ).innerHTML = e.editor.getData();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: @fermionoid you need to use `editor.on('keyup', function(){` instead of `editor.on('key', function(){`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs it, here's one way to get the TEXT value of an HTML field (used in this case for a dynamic character counter):

JS ...

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'myDoc', {
    width: 605,
    height: 500
});

setInterval("updateCount()", 500);

function updateCount() {
    var str = CKEDITOR.instances.myDoc.getData();
    if (str) {
        var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( str );
        var no_html = element.getText();
        $('#myDoc_length').html( no_html.length );
    }
}
```

... with HTML ...

```
<textarea id="myDoc"></textarea>
<span id="myDoc_length">0</span> characters
```